# ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast android.intent.action.MCC_CHANGED from system 2447:com.android.phone/1001 pkg com.android.phone

Tags: android, proguard, manifest, release

Here I am facing this crash after build release apk and try to install app on device. Seems like having conflict with proguard, if it's disable then it works fine. Please share your relevant answers.

Comment: Are you using any customized broadcast?

Answer (score 0):

add broadcast action to whitelist；
file：
frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java
checkBroadcastFromSystem()

or

broadcast define permission for the action;